# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key

Tags: java

I'm getting an encryption exception.

I'm running

- OS X 10.11
- Java 1.8
- Groovy Version: 2.4.4
- Gradle 2.3-20141027185330+0000;
- JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home

I installed the Oracle JCE Policy jars into my $JAVA_HOME/lib/security directory:

```
$ ls -l $JAVA_HOME/lib/security
total 16
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  2487 Oct  9 17:21 US_export_policy.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  2500 Oct  9 17:21 local_policy.jar
```

Here's the exception:

```
com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.lookup.AccountLookupSpec > constructor missing encryptor FAILED
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.initCipher(CipherUtils.java:110)
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.AesBytesEncryptor.encrypt(AesBytesEncryptor.java:65)
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.HexEncodingTextEncryptor.encrypt(HexEncodingTextEncryptor.java:36)
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at com.distributedfinance.mbi.bai.lookup.AccountLookupSpec.setup(AccountLookupSpec.groovy:26)
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Caused by:
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1034)
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:800)
19:05:00.431 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:859)
19:05:00.432 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1370)
19:05:00.432 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1301)
19:05:00.432 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.initCipher(CipherUtils.java:105)
19:05:00.432 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             ... 3 more
```

Code Snippet:

```
import com.distributedfinance.mbi.payment.repository.AccountRepository
import com.distributedfinance.mbi.domain.Account
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor


class AccountLookupSpec extends Specification {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountLookupSpec.class)

    AccountLookup accountL ookup
    List<Account> accounts
    AccountRepository accountRepository
    TextEncryptor encryptor

    def setup() {
        accountRepository = Mock()
        encryptor = Encryptors.text("password", "991239bab013")

        accounts = new ArrayList<Account>()
        Account account = new Account()
        account.setAccountNumber(encryptor.encrypt("1234567890"))
    }
...
```

}

Comment: Can you put your encryption code else how we can figure out if you can making some error ??

Comment: Those files are not the correct sizes for the Oracle JDK8 unlimited-strength policy jars, but they are the correct sizes for the JDK7 ones. Make sure you use the download for 8.

Comment: You right!  Issue resolved!

Answer (score 11):

The most common reason for this issue is /lib/security does'nt have the **Install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files**

[Download the Java 7 jar from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

[Download the Java 8 jar from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Follow the read me file and you should be up and running

Answer (score 1):

Other reasons this can happen:

- you're not using the JDK instead of JRE in your project
- you did not put the policy jars in the right folder (basically JDK/jre/lib/security -- see the readme).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command to download JCE 8.

```
curl -q -L -C - -b "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -o /tmp/jce_policy-8.zip \
   -O http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jce/8/jce_policy-8.zip && \
   unzip -oj -d /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security \
   /tmp/jce_policy-8.zip \*/\*.jar \
   && rm /tmp/jce_policy-8.zip
```

This assumes you have an Oracle JVM 8 at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be probably issue on `VERSION mismatch of JAVA JRE`

I have fixed by UPGRADING JRE VERSION from `jdk1.8.0_111\jre` to `jdk1.8.0_181\jre`

Hope you won't have to have additional libraries.